# Servlets + JAX-WS

Tags: java, servlets, jax-ws

I'm trying to expose a web service method via JAX-WS annotations. Many examples I've seen reference the EndPoint.publish() method to quickly stand up the service in a standalone app (ex from Java Web Services: Up and Running, 1st Edition):

```
public class TimeServerPublisher {
public static void main(String[ ] args) {
  // 1st argument is the publication URL
  // 2nd argument is an SIB instance
  Endpoint.publish("http://127.0.0.1:9876/ts", new TimeServerImpl());
}
```

}

One thing that I'm missing is how to accomplish essentially the same thing but in an existing app. Would I make a servlet to handle this? What is the proper way to publish this service in an existing WAR file?

Answer (score 4):

In a container you don't have to publish like this. The container will do the publish. If you plan to use it in JBoss server try JBossWS otherwise for Tomcat or any other server Axis2 may be the better choice.

Read more from the following links.

http://jbossws.jboss.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=JBossWS

http://ws.apache.org/axis2/

Answer (score 3):

This depends on what WS stack you are using.

If you are using Java 6 then that includes the [JAX-WS reference implementation](http://jax-ws.dev.java.net), then you can consult the [documentation about JAX-WS RI WAR contents](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/nonav/2.1.5/docs/jaxws-war.html).

Answer (score 1):

As @Jerrish and @andri coments, there are different aproaches and solutions, depending on your concerns.

The idea behind is that you don't need to set the configuration (port, etc) when will be published your web service. The best approach could be to set this via configuration files (XML, properties, etc) or using @Annotations.

For example, if you're accustomed to use frameworks like Guice or Spring, you know that is possible/recommended to start the context of your application publishing or initializing some objects, factories, datasources, etc and publishing webservices is another task that can be done in this time, because will be available when you will start your application, isn't?.

By the way, I've good experiences with CXF and another solution could be [Spring Web Services](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/) another powerful solution for creating web services.